# How can I filter lines via a numeric range?

Tags: awk

This file just has a single column:

```
fs://derps123/20210103/
fs://derps123/20210104/
fs://derps123/20210105/
fs://derps123/20210106/
fs://derps123/20210107/
fs://derps123/20210108/
fs://derps123/20210109/
```

I want to filter lines between `20210105` and `20210108`

I tried to filter using awk with `date` but this throws a syntax error:

```
awk -v date='gs://derps123/''$1!=date{next};/20210105/,/20210108/' folders.txt
```

Comment: Are the lines ordered by the date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get a syntax error because you have no whitespace between value of
`-v` option and awk program.

You can treat dates like numbers like that:

```
$ awk -v low=20210105 -v high=20210108 -v FS='/' '$4 >= low && $4 <= high' folders.txt
fs://derps123/20210105/
fs://derps123/20210106/
fs://derps123/20210107/
fs://derps123/20210108/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with sed:

```
sed -n '/20210105/,/20210108/p' folders.txt
```

Comment: This isn't doing numeric comparison, it's selecting all lines between the one that contains "20210105" and the one that contains "20210108". If the file isn't sorted in numeric order and/or there aren't lines containing these specific values, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `awk` at all. `grep` suffice:

```
grep '2021010[5-8]' you_data
```

This works even if the file is not sorted by date.

But, if you would like to use `awk` :

```
awk -F/ -v r=2021010[5-8] '$(NF-1) ~ r' your_data
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 awk -F "/" '$(NF-1)>=20210105 && $(NF-1)<=20210108'  filename

fs://derps123/20210105/
fs://derps123/20210106/
fs://derps123/20210107/
fs://derps123/20210108/
```

Comment: Could you explain how this is better than Arkadiusz’s existing AWK-based answer?